# How prove this $\left|\prod_{k=1}^{n}\sin{(\theta-a_{k})}\right|\ge\dfrac{1}{2^n}$

Tags: triangulation

let $a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},\cdots,a_{n}\in(0,\pi)$, show that
there exsit $\theta\in(0,\pi)$ such
$$\left|\prod_{k=1}^{n}\sin{(\theta-a_{k})}\right|\ge\dfrac{1}{2^n}$$

My try: 
$$\Longleftrightarrow |\prod_{k=1}^{n}2\sin{(\theta-a_{k})}|\ge 1$$

Then I can't prove it,Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Expand

$$\prod \sin(\theta-a_k)=\prod \frac{1}{2i}\left[e^{i(\theta-a_k)}-e^{i(\theta-a_k)}\right]$$

Let $f(\theta)=\prod\left[e^{2i(\theta-a_k)}-1\right]$. It suffices to show that there exists some $\theta$, such that $|f(\theta)|\ge 1$. Prove it by average(integral) method.

Comment: Hello,can you post your follow average methods? Thank you

Comment: @math110 Notice that $\int_{0}^{\pi} f(\theta)=\pi$, so there exists some $\theta$ such that $f(\theta)\ge 1$.

Comment: why $\int_{0}^{\pi}f(\theta)d\theta=\pi$

Comment: If you expand the formula as a sum of terms of the form $\exp(2k\theta+c)$, after integrating every term would be zero except the constant one.